# GraphFrame: Problem in finding diameter of a simple graph pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, graph, pyspark

I'm new to using graphFrames and pyspark. I'm looking for a way to get maximum shortest path length starting from specified nodes.
I read my data like:

```
data = spark.read.csv('class.csv', sep='\t', header = False)

links = data.withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'src').withColumnRenamed('_c1','dst')
nodes = links.select(F.col('src').alias('id')).union(links.select('dst')).alias('id')

graph = GraphFrame(nodes, links)
```

So nodes are like:

```
    |id |
    +---+
    |7  |
    |51 |
    |15 |
    |11 |
```

And edges are like:

```
|src|dst|
+---+---+
|  1|  4|
|  1|  5|
|  1| 37|
|  2| 15|
|  2| 25|
|  2| 51|
```

I tend to calculate all shortest paths first, then find longest path length for each id, then aggregate and get the maximum path length in graph. I know we can use BFS for it too but in this approach I want to try shortestPaths method and learn aggregate functions in pyspark better. I found paths like:

```
landmarks = graph.vertices.rdd.map(lambda x: x.id).collect()
results = graph.shortestPaths(landmarks = landmarks)
results.select('id','distances').show()
```

The result is:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|           distances|
+---+--------------------+
| 25|[45 -> 2, 12 -> 4...|
| 51|[45 -> 3, 12 -> 5...|
|  7|[45 -> 4, 12 -> 6...|
| 44|[45 -> 4, 12 -> 1...|
```

Can anyone help how to write query to get what I want?